# What is the purpose of "that" in "I wonder how close that I came"?

Tags: lyrics, poetry

This is from the song "[Worthless](https://genius.com/David-newman-worthless-lyrics)" by Van Dyke Parks from the movie *The Brave Little Toaster*.

> I once ran the Indy 500
> I must confess I'm impressed how I did it
> I wonder how close **that** I came

What is the purpose of "that" here? I think it is unnecessary because "wonder" usually takes a regular interrogative clause.

Comment: It is not grammatical in my variety of English. I think it may be dialectal.

Comment: Song lyrics, like poetry, often add or remove words to make things fit the meter.

Comment: The purpose seems to be to add a syllable in that line of the lyrics.

Answer (score 1):

In songs or poetry, we often add words to make the lyrics smoother or simply just to let it rhyme.